# Reading csv files with python gets me to the last line

Tags: python, csv

This might be a really dumb question but I've been stuck there for more than an hour.

I am doing some csv-file reading with python using the following code:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        print("Line = "+str(line))
        array = line.split(';')
        time = float(array[TIMEPOS])
        print("Initial time = "+str(time))
```

I have a huge number of lines in this csv file. And I see them all with the `print("Line = "+str(line))`. However, I only see "Initial Time = XXX" once, even though it should be displayed for every line.

I would very much like to know what I'm doing here that is wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: just in case you're not familiar with it, the [python csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) has saved me a lot of headache when dealing with csv files e.g. out of excel. don't see the problem with your code, sorry..

Comment: Please check that you're not mixing tabs and spaces in your code

Comment: Do you only see the final time?  If so, I suspect that you have an indentation issue such that python thinks that the `print("Initial time = "+str(time))` is not part of the `for` loop.

Comment: @ChrisMueller I see all my lines with the first print but only the final time indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I open your question for editing and "walk" my cursor through your code, I see that your indentations use a combination of spaces and tabs. This is bad in Python code: the interpreter does have rules on understanding this but those rules are basically un-followable for humans.

Replace all your tabs with spaces, and try your code again. And change your code editor so it uses only spaces, never tab characters.

Comment: As pointed out by you and @ChrisMueller, this was the problem indeed. Apparently I had a broken tab somewhere. Thanks everyone :)